# Navigation search suggestion with

Tags: javascript, html, css, codeigniter

I have an `input` with `autocomplete="off"`.
I have a `div` where search results are supposed to be.
Div's display (none, block) and ajax search (for results) works.
I want to navigate search results with keyboard arrows (down and up) like in Google.
E.g. I typed something in my input. Then I got search results. Then I need to navigate with "down arrow" and I need to rewrite (as click on the link) "Enter" button action as it is done in google.
I use CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try out [jQuery UI's Autocomplete Plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/). It has everything you need.

Click on the various examples on the right to see if it has everything you want. It's also relatively easy to style however you wish.